# How to judge 5G network connection type in cordova-plugin-network-information plugin？

Tags: android

I know cordova-plugin-network-information plugin can help classify connected network to different types:

```
Connection.UNKNOWN
Connection.ETHERNET
Connection.WIFI
Connection.CELL_2G
Connection.CELL_3G
Connection.CELL_4G
Connection.CELL
Connection.NONE
```

I want to know how to add 5G network type classification. Thanks in advance.